# How to create a ui button for SeaMonkey

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, seamonkey

I'm trying to get my extension (using Firefox Addon SDK 1.17) to work on SeaMonkey (2.30). After modifying install.rdf to allow my extension to be installed, I can see SeaMonkey accepted the extension. However -- my extension's button isn't visible anywhere in the UI. I am using `sdk/ui/button/toggle`. I have also tried `require("sdk/ui").ActionButton` but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

What do I need to do to make sure my extension can render a button into SeaMonkey's toolbar?

Comment: This guy named patrickjdempsey at this forum here is a seamonkey expert, maybe posting here would be better: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is that SeaMonkey does not officially support the Addon SDK yet. Support is planned for SeaMonkey 2.33

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1. patch the sdk to allow support on seamonkey.
2. copy the button code from the sdk into your add-on, mark it as supporting seamonkey, and use that, possibly uploading the code to npm as a third party module.